# How to export inner levels of treemap chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a treemap chart with one level down, and when I go down to it I cant export that view : instead it is exporting the top level...

```
 Highcharts.chart('container', {                  
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },              
            series: [{                 
                type: 'treemap',
                layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
                allowDrillToNode: true,
                animationLimit: 1000,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false                      
                },
                levelIsConstant: false,
                levels: [{
                    level: 1,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true
                    },
                    borderWidth: 3
                }],
                data: points
            }],
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Subtitle'
            },
            title: {
                text: "Title"
            }
        });
```

fiddle example: >>
http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/773871/

[image]

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with your libraries, are you using an old version? Here is your fiddle with the most recent libraries: http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/7a91hj4z/. As you can see it works as you expect it to work.

Comment: @ewolden the version im using is 4.2.3 and i didnt find anything that the version is problem... there was a similar problem with 4.1.9 though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs because you using the old version of Highcahrts. If you cannot use the newest release for some reason, all is not lost. Please paste the `wrap` function before generating the chart, and also create an empty object of `exporting.chartOptions.chart.events` in your chart configuration. Then it will call `drillToNode` function on specific id during every exporting.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype, 'drillToNode', function(proceed, id, redraw) {
    this.chart.options.exporting.chartOptions.chart.events.load = function() {
      this.series[0].drillToNode(id)
    }
    proceed.call(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
  })
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.treemap.prototype, 'drillUp', function(proceed) {
    this.chart.options.exporting.chartOptions.chart.events.load = function() {
      this.series[0].drillup()
    }
    proceed.call(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1))
  })
})(Highcharts)
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/pwtdq8yf/

Comment: thanks for the help, but one small problem from the fiddle, when you go down one level and when you go up, the back button text is gone...

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrap for the new version of Highcharts. Here is the fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/o2dLxn8v/ .